# Choosing に over を in 使役形 depends not solely on the verb

Tags: grammar, causation

Consider the following sentences:

1. 子供は本を読む。
2. 母は子供[に]{LL}本を読ませる。

Since 読む is a transitive verb (i.e.: 本を読む), に is used to mark the *causee* (i.e.: 子供) for its causative form 読ませる.

Now, consider the following sentences (not sure whether they are correct):

3. 子供は読む。
4. 母は子供[を]{LL}読ませる。

Even though, 読む is a verb that accepts a direct object, it's not taking one. Therefore, を is used to mark the *causee* 子供 for its causative form 読ませる.

It seems that, what determines whether to choose を or に for marking the *causee* in a causative verb, is not the verb per se, but actually **how** the verb is used in the sentence. Of course, if the verb is intransitive it will be always を, but for a transitive verb it may be either に or を.

Am I missing something?

Comment: `if the verb is intransitive it will be always を` -- But.. 明鏡国語辞典 carries example sentences: 「代理として娘**に／を**行かせる」「私**に**も休ませてください」 ... (Sorry if I'm only confusing you..)

Comment: Sorry, I've edited the question for using the right terms (*causee* instead of *non-causing person*) and now I can't mark it as "It answers my question" eve if I roll it back. Thanks a lot! The link is very useful and does indeed answer my question.

Comment: 母は子供を読ませる makes no sense (it would mean "Mom makes someone read her child"). It's because 読む is a transitive verb. Please see the link for details.

Comment: @naruto Thanks for the link. I think it's not really the same what you are talking about, since I am not providing a direct object for 読む in the two last sentences. Do I have then always to provide a direct object when using a transitive verb?? Can't I just say 子供は読む or 子供は食べる ?

Comment: @眠りネロク Please see the 子供に磨かせた example in the linked question. It's whether the verb **can** take を in the plain non-causative version, not whether the object is explicitly presented now.

Comment: @naruto Thanks again, I think I get it now. 母は子供を読ませる would actually mean: *The mother makes someone read the kid*. Therefore, the agent has to be marked with に.